# How to set variable of input type radio

Tags: php

I am trying to set variable of radio. But I see a notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: response in D:\xamp\htdocs\bombaytales\includes\backend_quiz.php on line 10 error.

My fronted code:

```
<form action="includes/backend_quiz.php" method="post">
   <?php
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM quiz order by rand() LIMIT 10") or die("Could not retrieve data: " .mysqli_error($conn));
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){           
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){               
                    extract($row);  
        ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
                    <h4><?php echo $id ?>.&nbsp  <?php echo $quation; ?></h4><br />

                    <input type="radio" name="response" value="a" /> <?php echo $opt1;?><br />
                    <input type="radio" name="response" value="b" /> <?php echo $opt2;?><br />
                    <input type="radio" name="response" value="c" /> <?php echo $opt3;?><br />
                    <input type="radio" name="response" value="d" /> <?php echo $opt4;?><br />
                    <br/>
                    <?php
            }
        }       
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="ans" value="Finish"/>
</form>
```

And my backend code:

```
if(isset($_POST['ans'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $rsp = $_POST['response'];
    $correctCount = 0;
}
```

Comment: i think your issue in  form php code section. mysqli_num_rows($query) return 0 i think

Comment: are checking the radio button? try `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);`

Comment: before submitting the form did you checked any radio button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code can be used to check if the 'response' radio is checked.
When the radio is unchecked, the variable will not be posted, thus the response variable will not be set.

```
    if (isset($_POST['ans'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        // check if radio button is checked.
        if (isset($_POST['response'])) {
            $rsp = $_POST['response'];
        }

        $correctCount = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add checked to any one of your input tag

Like:

```
<input type="radio" name="response" value="a" checked /> <?php echo $opt1;?><br />
```